# If $x$ is an algebraical element over $F$, then $F(x) = F[x]$

Tags: field-theory

Let $K / F$ be an extension of fields and let $F[X]$ be the ring of polynomials $\sum_{i = 0}^n a_i X^i$, where $n \in \mathbb{N}$ and $a_i \in F$ for all $i = 1 , \ldots , n$. The inclusion $F[x] \subset F(x)$ is trivial for all  $x \in K$, being
$$
F(X) = \left\{\frac{p(X)}{q(X)} : p(X) , q(X) \in F[X] \mbox{ and } q(X) \not \equiv 0\right\}\mbox{,}
$$
but also $F(x) \subset F[x]$ if $x$ is an algebraic element over $F$. How can I prove that? In other words, how can I show that there exists $\frac{p(x)}{q(x)} \in F(x)$ such that it does not belong to $F[x]$ if $x$ is trascendent over $F$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $x$ is algebraic over $F$, then $F[x]$ is a finite dimensional vector space over $F$: indeed let $f$ be the minimal polynomial for $x$; if you have a polynomial $g$, then $g=fq+r$, with the degree of $r$ less than the degree of $f$ and $g(x)=r(x)$. Hence, if the degree of $f$ is $n$, $F[x]$ is spanned by $\{1,x,\dots,x^{n-1}\}$.

Let now $g$ be a polynomial with $\deg g<\deg f$, with $g(x)\ne0$. Then, as $f$ is irreducible, $\gcd(f,g)=1$, so by Bézout there exist polynomials $p$ and $q$ with $1=pf+qg$. This implies
$$
q(x)g(x)=1
$$
so $q(x)\in F[x]$ is the inverse of $g(x)$.

If instead $x$ is transcendental over $F$, then $\frac{1}{x}\notin F[x]$.

Comment: Thank you very much by your explanation. I have two questions: why $\frac{1}{x} \notin F[x]$? (does it depend on $x$ is trascendental over $F$?) And if I show that $F[x]$ is a field, with $x$ trascendental over $F$, does it imply that $F[x] = F(x)$?

Comment: @joseabp91 (I assume $x\ne0$, of course.) If $1/x=a_0+a_1x+\dots+a_nx^n$, then $-1+a_0x+a_1x^2+\dots+a_nx^{n+1}=0$, and therefore $x$ is algebraic over $F$. Therefore, when $x$ is transcendental it is not invertible in $F[x]$ and therefore $F[x]$ is *not* a field. In the previous part I showed that if $x$ is *algebraic*, then every nonzero element of $F[x]$ has an inverse in $F[x]$, so $F[x]$ is a field.

Comment: Thank you, I understand now. I am grateful to you!